# single point stereo m/s NOT shotgun

Tags: stereo, mid-side, microphone, field-recording, ambience

I've been unsuccessfully looking for a single point stereo MS mic, that isn't a shotgun, for some time.

I had the Sony ECM MS957 many years ago and that's hardly professional.

I've used the VP88 for a few years and it's simply too noisy for ambient work.

I see there is now the MS957PRO - but is it really pro?

Surely there's a better option out there?

They no longer make the Pearl MS mics and a full Schoeps MS set is a little too bulky and expensive for my needs.

Anybody got any better ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Does "Single Point" mean that it's contained all in one mic body?

Comment: @Utopia - yes, a single stereo MS microphone on one body.

Comment: A Schoeps CCM ms set is about the smallest (and one of the nicest) MS systems you can get...it fits inside a Rycote ballgag. 

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

http://audiomonde.hu/index2.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_view&gid=1291&Itemid=181

Comment: @utopia these are the Pearl mics i mention in my question. I believe they are no longer manufactured. I do keep an eye out on ebay, but i'm told they are a little noisy also.

Comment: @analoghell OH lol... Sorry! I heard they have poor shielding, too. I can tell the Schoeps booth at NAB that there is an interest in an M/S mic that's not a shotgun.

Comment: How about this? http://www.sanken-mic.com/upload/pdf/en/cms-7s.pdf

Comment: http://www.neumann.com/?lang=en&id=current_microphones&cid=usm69_description

Comment: http://www.neumann.com/?lang=en&id=hist_microphones&cid=sm69fet_publications (if you can find one)

Comment: thanks, good suggestions, but these are both studio mics really and I believe these both require mains power. the reason i'm looking for a single-point mic is portability. 


Comment: @analoghell Alrighty. Well, I tried =/ Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well the only other one I know of is the [Ambient Products Emesser](http://www.ambient.de/produkte/mikrofone/emesser/emesser_e.html), but I get the feeling that this isn't what you're gonna want.  By single point I assume you mean a single unit that it's an M/S system contained in a single chassis.

Comment: indeed. I believe the Emesser is designed to work with shotguns? Though I don't see why it wouldn't with something like a MKH 8050.

Still, the single body aspect is crucial to my requirements.


Comment: @analoghell, I don't pretend to be an authority on the matter, but apart from the sony mic you mentioned above, I've never heard of a single unit that does M/S.  

Comment: @analonghell, I don't know how DIYish you are but I just found these schematics to make your own...http://www.mp3forkidz.com/mic/msmicV2.html.  There's also the 9506k from PAIA, http://www.paia.com/proddetail.asp?prod=9506K, but it looks like it's stand mounted and would be rather trixy to suspend in a blimp.

Comment: @g.a.harry thanks - i think you may be correct. i'm aware of the various DIY kits and plans, but while my electronics skills are ok, my machining skills are not! Anything I could make would really not be up to the rigours of traveling and field recording in general.



Answer (score 0):

There is also the avantone CK40, i've never heard it
but i'd love to try it curious

http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/CK40/

Answer (score 0):

I know its not really an M/S mic, but how about the Soundfield ST350?

Its single-point, portable (fits in a rycote) and high quality. The pre-amp can also be switched to output M/S instead of Left/Right. And if you've got the track count, B-Format!

It's a little bit expensive though...

http://www.soundfield.com/products/st350.php

[Soundfield ST350 http://www.studiocare.com/store/images/products/Soundfield/SSOVST350_2.jpg](http://www.studiocare.com/store/images/products/Soundfield/SSOVST350_2.jpg)

Comment: If one was to buy a ST350, one should wait for the ST450.
http://www.soundfield.com/news/news_st450.php

Also, working with B-Format, there's a new B-Format decoder I've been beta testing that's now available, the Harpex-B. http://harpex.net/download.html The Harpex-B is the best 1st order B-Format decoder for tetrahedral microphones (SoundField, Core Sound, DIY), even if you're only working in stereo.